# Derivative of a generalized eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I want to compute the derivative of a generalized eigenvalue $\lambda$ which is solution of $A u = \lambda Bu$ ($A,B,u,\lambda$ all depend on $t$; in my case $A,B$ are known explicitly, and the eigenvalue $\lambda$ and its corresponding eigenvector $u$ can be immediately computed using eigs).

If I write formally the derivation, I arrive to the problem 
$$ (A-\lambda B)u' = -(A'-\lambda B')u+\lambda' Bu \ \ \ (1)$$
In the above equation I know $A,B,\lambda,u,A',B'$. The unknowns are $\lambda'$ and $u'$. If $A,B$ are symmetric, we can get rid of $u'$ by taking the scalar product with $u$. In my case $A,B$ are not always symmetric, so I need to solve $(1)$ with both unknowns $u'$ and $\lambda'$.

This has the form $Xu' = v+\lambda ' w$ where $X$ is a known matrix (non-invertible) and $v,w$ are known vectors.

> How can we compute $u'$ and $\lambda'$?

Comment: To eliminate $u'$, take the scalar product with $v$, where $v$ is the *left* eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then continue you would in the symmetric case.

Comment: That's a very good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The eigenproblem you have doesn't have a unique solution, any multiple
of $u$ solves it as well. So suppose we impose the condition
$u^tu=1$. The *two* equations are
$$ Au=\lambda Bu, \qquad u^Tu=1, $$
giving derivatives
$$ (A-\lambda B)u' -\lambda' Bu = (\lambda B'-A')u, \qquad 2u^T u' =
0. $$

This is nothing but a system of $n+1$ equations in $n+1$ unknowns:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
A-\lambda B & -B u\\ u^T & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}u'\\ \lambda' \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
  (\lambda B'-A')u\\
  0
\end{pmatrix}, $$
which should have a unique solution, provided *this* matrix is nonsingular, which should happen whenever $\lambda$ has multiplicity 1.

Comment: Nice answer. Adding the normalization condition and making a $(n+1)\times  (n+1)$ system is a nice way to solve this.